# Where to put welcome activity code

Tags: java, android

I searched a lot but i did not find my answer. I have developed an android application where on the very first lunch user will be shown a welcome screen made of viewpager. The problem is i don't know which place is the  best to put the welcome activity code in my application.

The simplest way it could be that in the main activity at the very fist line even before **super.onCreate()**, inside onCreate method where i try to get the shared preference value and then evaluate whether it is fist lunch. If it is, then i start the welcome activity as shown below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean welcome = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.key_welcome), true);
        if (welcome) {
            // go and start welcoming activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeSlideActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

But i found another approach to deal with it. It is Application class. Since Application class is the first one, which runs even before any other codes in my application. So i thought, i would be nice to do it there as shown below

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean welcome = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.key_welcome), true);
        if (welcome) {
            // go and start welcoming activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeSlideActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

So i am in dilemma, which one would be the best option to choose. And i am even not sure if i am doing it in the right way since there is no such documentation in android developer website or anywhere.

Comment: You want to show WelcomeSlideActivity just once after user first time launch your app?

Comment: yes, i want to do that but in the best way as the professional apps do

Comment: I used that once to show pop up dialog in my app with `SharedPreferences` with just simple `if`checking and still it's working great. Of course if user reinstalls the app welcome dialog will show again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at how to create splash screens the correct way. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

As for using the `Application` class - this is primarily used for Application-wide configuration for maintaining a global application state. Hence starting an activity from here does not make much sense as it's purpose has changed into becoming an entry point into the application rather than providing state for the app as a whole.

Furthermore, why not make the `WelcomeSlideActivity` the first 'launcher' activity? Then in there, you can create the logic of whether to launch the next activity without history or whether to show the current view.

Ideally, you should create a splash screen activity, which determines whether to show the `WelcomeSlideActivity` Or the `MainActivity`. The advantage of this is that while he app determines which Activity to launch, the user is presented with a splash screen that informs the user that the app has started

Comment: let's say i have made that welcomeSlideActivity as the launcher activity. On the very first time the activity will show the welcoming stuff, but then on each launch it will be seemed to do nothing at all just taking user to the next activity wasting memory or slowing performance for nothing. So what do you think?

Comment: @xFighter If you opt for developing a sliding welcome screen and get uptight about showing it up every lunch, the standard behaviour is to show it only for the first lunch. This is no brainer to implement since all you need to do is maintain a flag on SharedPreference.

Comment: @blackpanther the link you gave i found it helpful but i can do the same without making any activity at all. I just need a theme and some configuration in manifests and in the main activity by the following code  setTheme(R.style.SplashAppTheme);